# Not a v4.0.0 POM. org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: maven-2

I am using maven 2.2.1 and when i try to build my project  i am getting the below exception.

```
Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin at /Users/<<userid>>/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.8.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.8.1.pom
```

Comment: Please show the full error output and not only exceprts...Why building with Maven 2.2.1 cause [Maven 2 is End Of Life](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)

Comment: Delete the folder `/Users/<<userid>>/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins` and try rebuild. Cause this message could be hint about not having correct internet connection to download the files...and you might get a 404 message which is stored into the pom file ...

Answer (score 0):

As in the error message,i just deleted the below directory from my local repo. And then ran the clean install, on the project again resolved the issue.

```
/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.8.1
```